# i want to add items into cart.is there any example with spring-mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, arraylist

i want to add items into cart.i want to write with spring-mvc.
in cart,i want to add name and price of item.If i press add to cart button each of the item,it must go to cart and display name and price.

i tried a few and it's not working

Comment: "i tried a few and it's not working" - Please share the same.